# Extraction of DEM from netCDF file into ASCII XYZ format using ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, convert, netcdf

I need to extract a DEM of a waterbody from a netCDF file so I can ultimately convert the DEM into xyz format. I'm not sure how to go about doing this, and so far, I have tried to create raster layers of the DEM in ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap). However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach to obtain the data in xyz format.

How could I go about handling this conversion?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org) to transform driectly from [NetCDF](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_netcdf.html) to [ASCII XYZ](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html) with the [`gdal_translate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) command. Start with [gdalinfo](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) to get the name of the band to extract (it will look something like `NETCDF:"filename.nc":dem_bnds`) to pass as the dataset, for example:

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ NETCDF:"filename.nc":dem_bnds dem.xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing, converting the GEBCO 2019.nc to an xyz for further processing. I'm using gdal via qgis tools, gdal2xyz. The interface is a little more intuitive vice command line. The conversion (elevation layer for z conversion) is Band 1. (default on my instance). The resulting .csv can be processed in any number of downstream tools